# why it is showing project name as "Default" in sitefinity dashboard portal once I run it

Tags: sitefinity

I am new to **Sitefinity**. But I followed steps from tutorial and created the one project named as "SFcmsDemo" and when I run this project and **Sitefinity** dashboard appears on localhost it is showing name as "Default" instead of "SFcmsDemo", The tutorial I read is showing the correct name in that but when I tried it is showing as "Default".  Can anyone please help me find out the root cause and solution for this.  I am attaching some screenshot which will help to understand more. Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default can be easily changed if you click on it and then **Manage Site**.

**UPDATE**

From the decompiled Telerik.Sitefinity.dll (v.12.2):

```
internal static Site GetOrCreateDefaultSite()
{
      Site site;
      string str = "CreateDefaultSite";
      MultisiteManager manager = MultisiteManager.GetManager(null, str);
      using (ElevatedModeRegion elevatedModeRegion = new ElevatedModeRegion(manager))
     {
         ProjectConfig projectConfig = Config.Get<ProjectConfig>();
         Guid siteMapRootNodeId = projectConfig.DefaultSite.SiteMapRootNodeId;
         Site site = (
                   from s in manager.GetSites()
                   where s.SiteMapRootNodeId == siteMapRootNodeId
                   select s).FirstOrDefault<Site>();
         if (site == null)
         {
             site = (projectConfig.DefaultSite.Id == Guid.Empty ? manager.CreateSite() : manager.CreateSite(projectConfig.DefaultSite.Id));
             site.IsDefault = true;
             site.IsOffline = false;
             site.site = projectConfig.DefaultSite.site;
             site.SiteMapRootNodeId = siteMapRootNodeId;

             site.Name = (projectConfig.ProjectName != "/" ? projectConfig.ProjectName : "Default");
                ....
```

Note in the last line how it looks in the projectConfig.ProjectName value and if it is equal to "/" then it sets it to "Default"

Now, if we look at the ProjectConfig there is this:

```
        [Browsable(false)]
        [ConfigurationProperty("projectName", DefaultValue="/")]
        [ObjectInfo(typeof(ConfigDescriptions), Title="ProjectNameTitle", Description="ProjectNameDescription")]
        public string ProjectName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["projectName"];
            }
            internal set
            {
                this["projectName"] = value;
            }
        }
```

So, default value is indeed "/", so that's why when the site is created it has a name of Default.

Comment: Thanks. But why did it not display it. From where it is getting this "Default" word and not the project name which gave since from the beginning?

Comment: I think what you enter initially is just the name of the folder where the project will be created. But then, when the first (initial) site is created, it always has the name Default.

Comment: Updated my answer above to provide more details